# No such module RealmSwift

Tags: swift, xcode, realm, swift4.2

This is not a duplicate question. 
I have been using realm for a long time. Recently I am getting the error of "No such module RealmSwift". But this is happening only in release target scheme not in build target scheme. Is there any particular reason as to why it is not working only in release? I have seen this question at a lot of places but none of those solutions worked for me.

My podfile looks similar to this:

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '12.0'

#use_modular_headers!

inhibit_all_warnings!

def shared_pods

  pod 'RealmSwift'

end


target ‘************’ do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for ************

  shared_pods

  target '************Tests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing

  end

end

target '************UITests' do
  inherit! :search_paths
  # Pods for testing

#  shared_pods
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a troubleshooting step than a direct answer since I duplicated your issue.

You've been using Realm a while so you know this but for future readers, ensure that any file where you're using RealmSwift includes

```
import RealmSwift
```

I just tried your podfile on a new project and am getting weird behavior as well. I replaced your podfile with the following 5 lines and it works correctly.

```
project 'Realm Test.xcodeproj'
target 'Realm Test' do
  use_frameworks!
  platform :osx, '10.13'
  pod 'RealmSwift'
end
```

That was a macOS project but it worked equally well with an iOS project. On that project I uncommented #platform :ios, '12.0'

I think this is the issue

```
inherit! :search_paths
```

That lets the target know about the search paths but does not link them in. I would suggest changing that to

```
inherit! :complete
```

Which appears to be working in my project.

Oh - for completness, I ran into this once as well and the solution was

> add the parent path of RealmSwift.framework (i.e., the containing
>   directory) to your framework search paths.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common Realm bug which occurs in Xcode after pod install. Clean and Build the project once, the bug should go away!